# How to move xampp between different computers?

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I want to take my project from my computer to another on a usb.can I do it without installing the xampp on the other computer and just carrying it with me on usb?

Comment: Sounds more like an administrator's job and not programmer. Remember: Stackoverflow is for programming-related, not administrative-related questions.

Comment: I just moved my entire /xampp folder and it works fine

Comment: I have made a project and want to take it to school.Whenever i start server on different computer it "shut downs unexpectedly'

Comment: Google "xampp usb" you should give some good results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your project everywhere, it is better use Portable version Xampp.
You can download this version from this [link](https://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp)

And then install it in USB flash drive.now you can run your project anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Download xampp from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/ and then copy it to the pen drive.Then run the setup_xampp.bat.
That's it!